# Create a CmdExec Job Step with t-sql inside

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, jobs

I want to execute a .exe with sql server. For security reasons I can't use the `xp_cmdshell`. So I decided to create job with a CmdExec Step.

The .exe file must receive 2 parameters. The problem is I never know the parameter.

Ex : I want to give 2 date, today and today + 1 day.

It is easy to do in T-sql, so it is possible to use t-sql INSIDE a CmdExec step ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frist,Create a Job with CmdExec step, command like this.

```
EXEC test.exe @Parm1, @Parm2
```

After that, in your code to execute .exe

```
 -- Update Job Step with real parameter
 UPDATE msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps 
 SET command = REPLACE(REPLACE(command,'@Parm1','NewParm1') ,'@Parm2','NewParm2')
 WHERE job_id = @YouJobIDHere
 AND step_id = @StepId 

 -- start job
  EXEC =  msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = @CustomJobName
```

Comment: So if I am doing that, the job will loose it sense. I want to execute the job every 2 h, so I ill have to create an other job that will execute the script to update the first job (who execute the .exe) and then execute the first job...